# Проблема с формированием JSON в webAPI ASP.Net

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, классы, asp.net-core

Стоит задача создания уникальных переменных, которые будут содеражать в себе настройки сервера. Задумывается так, что эти переменные можно будет получать в формате json через Web API.

Для этих серверных переменных создаю класс:

```
public class Settings
{
   public static readonly int MaxCount = 10000;
   public int CountryServer = 123; //Для теста
   public static readonly int BaseValue = 146;
}
```

Далее создаю WebAPI:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ServerController : ControllerBase
{
   // GET: api/Server/action
   [HttpGet("[action]")]
   public IActionResult ServerSettings()
   {
      Settings settings = new Settings();
      return Ok (settings);
   }
}
```

Однако, при обращении к api в json получаю только переменную `CountryServer`

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С помощью отладчика понял, что остальне переменные вошли в ктегорию `static members` (вполне логично) в `settings`

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходя из всего вышеуказанного возникает 2 вопроса:

1. Как можно решить эту проблема (что в json попадали все 3 параметра), оставляя их статическими - только для чтения?
2. Как ещё (желательно, более корректно) реализовать данного рода задачу?

По решению прблемы 1 вопроса появилось следующее ужасно-костыльное решение:

```
public class Settings
{
    private static readonly int MaxCount = 10000;
    public int CountryServer = 123; //Для теста
    private static readonly int BaseValue = 146;
    public int maxCount = MaxCount;
    public int baseValue = BaseValue;
}
```

Конечно, так работает, но при этом плодить кучи одинаковых переменных, да ещё и так - не вариант.

Comment: а кто вам мешает сделать переменные public static readonly?

Comment: @Monomax так они и есть public static readonly и из-за того, что они статические, в return Ok() они не включаются в сформированный json. В этом та вся и проблема.

Comment: 1) Написать `SettngsProvider` класс с методом `Settings GetSettings()`

Comment: 2) зарегать его в DI как Синглтон

Comment: 3) Использовать DI для получения провайдера в конструкторе контроллера

Comment: 4) Больше никогда не париться с проблемами статических полей

Comment: @tym32167 можете, пожалуйста, привести пример. 2 и 3 пункты не очень понял. Спасибо.

Comment: @tym32167 Правильно понял, что  надо объявить переменные в appsettings.json?

Comment: вы используете asp.net core, так? У вас есть Startup методы, где вы регстрируете свои сервисы. Напишите сервис, который возвращает настройки сервера и зарегайте там его синглтогом